# Swift5 Status Bar Color for iOS - keep white color of battery, signal indicator

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have table view controller which is embedded into a navigation controller. Basically I want my app to look like the "alarm" app from iOS: complete app is black including the navigation bar, but I want the top line where the carrier, battery life etc. is shown to be also black but with white text font. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to any/all view controllers:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the status bar of a specific screen/ViewController, add it to the following class.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

If you want the whole app to have the same status bar color, then you can do it the following ways -

1. Inside the project settings - click the project, and under **General** and **Deployment Info** select the **Status bar style** to however you want.
   [See image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b6EC.png)
2. Go to info.plist and add a new row, Type in Status Bar Style and set the value to whichever you want.